# Taking "Magic Initiate" as a Monk

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

What if you're a human variant that starts as a monk and the Magic Initiate feat? How would that work out? No caster levels but has taken the feat then at Level 4 takes spell sniper feat? Any ideas?

Comment: This is what I want to post but can't. What if your a human variant that starts as a monk and the Magic Initiate feat? How would that work out? No caster levels but has taken the feat then at Level 4 takes spell sniper feat? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking a question about the rules?  What you're proposing is legal, but that's all a Q&A site is appropriate to tell you.  You might want a discussion forum if you're after ideas rather than simple answers.

Comment: Also, what was the title you tried to give your question? This would help understand why it did not work.

Answer (score 4):

You will have a monk with two cantrips and 1/day level 1 spell. Choosing Cleric or Druid can give you ranged[1] options to attack with wisdom, and Druids have Shillelagh for scaling Wisdom based melee damage.

A level one spell cast from a level 1 slot has its base effect, no matter what the source of the spell and slot.

[1] Thorn whip is a melee spell attack with a 30ft range, so I list it as a ranged option